# MediaPlayer method. PrepareAsync() does not call the onPrepared method

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I've been trying to build a simple service for listening to music in the background.
In the function onCommandStart I call Prepare async on the Mediaplayer object.
For some reason, the function OnPrepared, where I start the audio, doesn't get called...

Here is my service class:

```
public class playService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener
        ,MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener,MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener,MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener
{
    public playService()
    {
    }
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayerMp3 = new MediaPlayer();
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mediaPlayerMp3.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayerMp3.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayerMp3.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mediaPlayerMp3.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
        mediaPlayerMp3.setOnInfoListener(this);
        mediaPlayerMp3.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        super.onCreate();
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        String strMp3Link = intent.getExtras().getString("mp3Link");
        if(!mediaPlayerMp3.isPlaying())
        {
            try
            {
                mediaPlayerMp3.setDataSource(strMp3Link);
                mediaPlayerMp3.prepareAsync();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)
    {
        if(!mediaPlayerMp3.isPlaying())
        {
            mediaPlayerMp3.start();
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

(I have all the other methods I implemented as well, they are just not relevant now.)

So I have a button, I press it, start the Intent (in MainActivity, it works fine) the function onStartCommand gets called. But when it reaches prepareAsync(), nothing happens. Audio isn't being played. How do I deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

If strMp3Link is a network URL of the audio stream, you also need to specify internet permission. Add the following to your application manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
...
```

Comment: I've had it there from the beginning, sadly it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you share a media link or file that is not working?

Comment: this is the link I'm using : "http://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-8.mp3"
I am doing as follows, in mainActivity:

```
strLink = "http://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-8.mp3";
        serviceIntent.putExtra("mp3Link", strLink);
        startService(serviceIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Starting audio...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Im not sure how to make it readable so sorry,,,

Comment: The problem is that you missed `https://` prefix.
The correct link will be `strLink = "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-8.mp3"`
`mediaPlayerMp3.setDataSource(strMp3Link)` use `Uri.parse(String)` method under the hood, which accepts RFC 2396-compliant, encoded URI. 
[See more](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)

Comment: it still doesn't work... I did what you said, when I run it, it just doesn't reach the onPrepared() method. I have no idea why.